# Shortest Path with Titan and Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, titan, tinkerpop, faunus

Currently we are using Titan Graph DB with Cassandra as backend for a telecom application. The database consists of Network topology details. We have a requirement to calculate the shortest path between network nodes based on the Dijkstra algorithm. Appreciate your suggestions on the following 
1 We feel running iterative traversal across vertices using simple traversal will not be efficient , please suggest if map/reduce is the best option for this. 
2 Do we need to use Faunus for this requirement or the existing setup with Faunus jar/libraries will enable us to carry out this. (With Furnace Dijkstra implementation??)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this question was answered in the Aurelius Graphs mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/Im3y93YOkz0

In short, Faunus is not the best tool for this job.  More discussion on this topic can be found here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/67m_5Uc34Yk/CMVLsKLHYOwJ